# Why is $PATH different in terminal emulator and inside tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux, path

I use lxterminal and this is my $PATH output in lxterminal,

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/bkc/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

However, inside tmux, some of the locations aren't shown.

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/bkc/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Starting it in my terminal. `tmux -u`

Comment: Because tmux starts a _login shell_ by default, and a login shell sources other initialization files (eg. `~/.bash_profile`) than a non-login one (eg. `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: See the end of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476691/308316) for a workaround.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks, that helped. I entered the locations `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin` into ~/.profile, and because login shells sources this file, now, the missing two locations appear while echoing $PATH inside tmux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @mosvy, as per the user's comment, I entered the locations `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin` into my `~/.profile` file.

Login shells sources `~/.profile` and therefore, now the missing locations are shown while `echo $PATH`.